# Is there a way to dynamically construct an svg in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

In my web app there is a hamburger making portion. The user starts off with a hamburger that has nothing but the top bun and the bottom bun. The user can choose from an assortment of "toppings" to add to the hamburger, and the changes are then shown. I have SVG files for the top bun, bottom bun, lettuce, patty, cheese, etc, and I wish to combine them (stack them) together dynamically in run time. I am currently able to stack them dynamically, but I wish to have certain SVG files overlap others.

I'll show you what I mean

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjYSv.png)

Above you can see that the hamburger starts off with nothing on it.
The react DOM looks something like

```
<img src = {topBunSVG}> </img>
<img src = {buttonBunSVG}> </img>
```

Let's click on tomato to add it.

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D5mI.png)

Now you can see that the tomato is now between the two buns. The DOM now looks like this

```
<img src = {topBunSVG}> </img>
<img src = {tomatoSVG}> </img>
<img src = {buttonBunSVG}> </img>
```

Same thing with adding a patty

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ofxy.png)

The DOM now looks like this

```
<img src = {topBunSVG}> </img>
<img src = {pattySVG}> </img>
<img src = {tomatoSVG}> </img>
<img src = {buttonBunSVG}> </img>
```

Lets try something more complex, like adding some cheese

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITOEx.png)

You can see that the cheese overlaps the other components

The DOM now looks like this

```
<img src = {topBunSVG}> </img>
<img src = {cheeseSVG}> </img>
<img src = {pattySVG}> </img>
<img src = {tomatoSVG}> </img>
<img src = {buttonBunSVG}> </img>
```

However, React actually displays it like this:

[React Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOATM.png)

Which is not what I want.

How would I make them stack correctly?

Also when I make the window smaller it looks like this:
[Responsive component resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l0Ff.png)

Here's the relevant code for the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import "./makeHamburger.scss";
import bottomBun from "../../assets/foodParts/hamburger/bottombun.svg"
import cheese from "../../assets/foodParts/hamburger/cheese.svg"
import lettuce from "../../assets/foodParts/hamburger/lettuce.svg"
import patty from "../../assets/foodParts/hamburger/patty.svg"
import tomato from "../../assets/foodParts/hamburger/tomato.svg"
import topBun from "../../assets/foodParts/hamburger/topbun.svg"






const parts = {
  topBun: {
    view: topBun,
    price: 1.5,
    macros: {
      carbs: 1,
      protein: 0,
      fiber: 0,
      fat: 0,
    },
  },
  bottomBun: {
    view: bottomBun,
    price: 1.5,
    macros: {
      carbs: 1,
      protein: 0,
      fiber: 0,
      fat: 0,
    },
  },
  patty: {
    view: patty,
    price: 5,
    macros: {
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 1,
      fiber: 0,
      fat: 0,
    },
  },
  cheese: {
    view: cheese,
    price: 1,
    macros: {
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0,
      fiber: 0,
      fat: 1,
    },
  },
  lettuce: {
    view: lettuce,
    price: 2,
    macros: {
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0,
      fiber: 1,
      fat: 0,
    },
  },
  tomato: {
    view: tomato,
    price: 2,
    macros: {
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0,
      fiber: 1,
      fat: 0,
    },
  },
}

const initialState = { contents: [parts.topBun, parts.bottomBun] };

function reducer(state, action) {
  let tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))
  switch (action.type) {
    case "addPatty":

      tmp.contents.splice(1, 0, parts.patty)
      return {
        contents: tmp.contents
      }
      break;
    case "addCheese":

      tmp.contents.splice(1, 0, parts.cheese)
      return {
        contents: tmp.contents
      }
      break;
    case "addLettuce":

      tmp.contents.splice(1, 0, parts.lettuce)
      return {
        contents: tmp.contents
      }
      break;
    case "addTomato":

      tmp.contents.splice(1, 0, parts.tomato)
      return {
        contents: tmp.contents
      }
      break;
    case "deletePartsById":

      if ((action.payload == 0) || (action.payload == (state.contents.length - 1))) {
        return state;
      }
      tmp.contents.splice(action.payload, 1)
      return {
        contents: tmp.contents
      }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}


const MakeHamburger = ({recieveFood}) => {

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);


  const getTotalPrice = () => {
    let price = 0;
    state.contents.forEach((item,index) => {
      price += item.price
    })

    return price;
  }

  const getTotalCarbs = () => {
    let carbs = 0;
    state.contents.forEach((item,index) => {
      carbs += item.macros.carbs
    })
    return carbs;
  }

  const getTotalFat = () => {
    let fat = 0;
    state.contents.forEach((item,index) => {
      fat += item.macros.fat
    })
    return fat;
  }

  const getTotalFiber = () => {
    let fiber = 0;
    state.contents.forEach((item,index) => {
      fiber += item.macros.fiber
    })
    return fiber;
  }

  const getTotalProtein = () => {
    let protein = 0;
    state.contents.forEach((item,index) => {
      protein += item.macros.protein
    })
    return protein;
  }

  const getTotalMacros = () => {
    return{
      carbs: getTotalCarbs(),
      protein: getTotalProtein(),
      fiber: getTotalFiber(),
      fat: getTotalFat(),
    }
  }

  return (
    <div id="food" className="container">
      <h1>Let's make Max a burger</h1>
      <p>Select what goes on the burger</p>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-6">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <button className="transparentButton" onClick={() => { dispatch({ type: 'addCheese' }) }}>
                  <img className="selectPartImg" src={cheese}></img>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <p>Cheese</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mt-3">
              <div className="col">
                <button className="transparentButton" onClick={() => { dispatch({ type: 'addLettuce' }) }}>
                  <img className="selectPartImg" src={lettuce}></img>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <p>Lettuce</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mt-3">
              <div className="col">
                <button className="transparentButton" onClick={() => { dispatch({ type: 'addPatty' }) }}>
                  <img className="selectPartImg" src={patty}></img>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col"><p>Patty</p></div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mt-3">
              <div className="col">
                <button className="transparentButton" onClick={() => { dispatch({ type: 'addTomato' }) }} >
                  <img className="selectPartImg" src={tomato}></img>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col"><p>Tomato</p></div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div className="col-6 ">
            {state.contents.map(function (part, i) {
              return <div className="row no-gutters">
                <div className="col">
                  <button className="transparentButton" onClick={() => { dispatch({ type: 'deletePartsById', payload: i }) }} >
                    <img className="partImg" src={part.view}></img>
                    
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            })}
            <h1>Total price: {getTotalPrice()}</h1>
            <p>({getTotalCarbs() ? getTotalCarbs() + " carbs" : null}{getTotalFat() ? ", " + getTotalFat() + " fat" : null}
            {getTotalFiber() ? ", " + getTotalFiber() + " fiber" : null}{getTotalProtein() ? ", " + getTotalProtein() + " protein" : null})</p>
            <button onClick = {() => {recieveFood(getTotalMacros())}}>Feed this burger</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  );
};

export default MakeHamburger;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggested answers everyone, I managed to solve the program with this code snippet:

```
    const drawParts = () => {

    

    let parts = [];

    let positionOffSet = 0;

    let z = state.contents.length;

    state.contents.map(function (part, index) {

      parts.push(
        <div className="row no-gutters"  style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: z, top: positionOffSet }}>
          <div className="col">
            <button className="transparentButton" onClick={() => { dispatch({ type: 'deletePartsById', payload: index }) }} >
              <img className="partImg" src={part.view}></img>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
      
      if(part.view == cheese){
        positionOffSet -= 90;
        z--;
      }

      if(part.view == lettuce){
        positionOffSet -= 15;
        z--;
      }

    })

    return parts;
   }
```

Basically having a global offset and z-value variable that gets incremented everytime a cheese or lettuce shows up. The offset and z-value is applied to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

If the height of one layer is not identical with the height of the image, you need to specify the height of each individual layer. (The information about the desired height just does not exist in the image).

#### (A) You can create SVG data dynamically:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const Patties = (props) => {
    return (<>
        { [...props.patties].reverse().map( function(patty, index){
            return <>
                <path d={ 'M 0 ' + (60 - index * 20) + ' h 100 l -50 30 z' } fill={ patty.color } />
            </>
        })}
    </>);
};

export const Hamburger = (props) => {
    return (
        <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width={ 200 }
            height={ 200 }
            viewBox={ [ 0, 0, 100, 100 ].join(' ') }
        >
            <Patties patties={[
                { color: '#fa0' },
                { color: '#0a0' },
                { color: '#c20' },
            ]}/>
        </svg>
    );
};
```

#### (B) You can use absolute positioning:

```
export const Hamburger2 = (props)=>{
    const patties = [
        { url: imgUrlA },
        { url: imgUrlB },
        { url: imgUrlC },
    ];

    return (<div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        { patties.reverse().map( function(patty, index){
            return <img
                src={ patty.url }
                style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 60 - index * 20 }}
            />;
        })}
    </div>);
};
```